# React.js: How to implement dark/light mode in body toggling with useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a background theme which will switch on **onClick**. On **onClick** it must change the background color of **body** in **react app**. I've managed to implement **useContext**, and now it toggles and changes the list items color in **Header component**. How to set it to **body** as well? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my useContext color component

```
import React from 'react'

export const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
  },
  blue: {
    foreground: 'blue',
  },
}

export default React.createContext({
  theme: themes.light,
  switchTheme: () => {},
})
```

onClick Button component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import ThemeContext from './context'

import './ThemedButton.scss'

const ThemedButton = () => {
  const { switchTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)

  return (
    <>
      <button className="btn" onClick={switchTheme}>
        Switch
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

export default ThemedButton
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import useCountries from './Hooks/useCountries';
import MainTable from './components/MainTable';
import ThemeButton from './useContext/ThemedButton';
import ThemeContext from './useContext/context';

import { searchProps } from './types';
import { themes } from './useContext/context';
import Routes from './Routes';


import './App.scss'

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [data] = useCountries(search)
  const [context, setContext] = useState({
    theme: themes.light,
    switchTheme: () => {
      setContext((current) => ({
        ...current,
        theme: current.theme === themes.light ? themes.blue : themes.light,
      }))
    },
  })

  const handleChange: React.ReactEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e): void => {
    setSearch(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchBar handleChange={handleChange} search={search as searchProps} />

      <ThemeContext.Provider value={context}>
        <ThemeButton />
        <MainTable countries={data} />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>

      <Routes />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Header component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import ThemeContext from '../../useContext/context'


import './Header.scss'

export default function Header() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext)

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <ul className="HeadtableRow" style={{ color: theme.foreground }}> // here it's set to change list items color
        <li>Flag</li>
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Language</li>
        <li>Population</li>
        <li>Region</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your `body` tag in your application you need to modify `DOM` and you can add this code to your Header.js (or any other file under your context) file:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].style.backgroundColor = theme.foreground
  },[])
```

> *** Don't forget to import `useEffect`
>
> *** Inline style like below is a better approach than modifying `DOM` directly

```
<div className="App" style={{backgroundColor: context.theme.foreground}}> 
     //For under context files just use theme.foreground
      <SearchBar handleChange={handleChange} search={search as searchProps} />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={context}>
        <ThemeButton />
        <MainTable countries={data} />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>

      <Routes />
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works fine. But why did you define it in UseEffect?
Can you explain it please?

Comment: I'm happy it helped @Greg . I've defined it in `useEffect` to make sure it applies changes after rendering `body` in `DOM` you can remove it from `useEffect`. Or add `foreground` to dependency array to improve its functionality!